# permutation module

Tags: group-cohomology

If *X* is a *G*-set, then the free abelian group *Z[X]* generated by *X* and extends the action of *G* on *X* to a **Z-linear action** of *G* on *Z[X]*. The resulting *G*-module is called a Permutation module. (Kenneth S. Brown, Cohomology of Groups, pg 13)
What does it meant by Z-linear action and how does permutation module looks like?
Please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear extension means $g\cdot\sum_{x\in X} z_xx = \sum_{x\in X}z_x(g\cdot x)$, where $z_x\in\mathbb Z$. Careful if $X$ is infinite.